# Why does inline destructuring as a function argument not work as expected

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Let's say I have code that requires access to a state object that looks like this

```
const store = {
  getState: () => ({
    a: "test",
    b: 1,
    c: 23,
  })
}
```

And a helper function that looks like this, the `rest` is to illustrate the fact that the output of this will not be JUST the destructured argument I passed in.

```
function printState ({a, b, ...rest}) {
  console.log(a, b, rest)
}
```

So if I try to use inline destructuring

```
printState({ a, b } = store.getState())
```

The output of above is

```
"test" 1 Object {
  c: 23
}
```

I would have expected only `a` and `b` to be passed in, and not the rest of the object. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: destructing lets you expose the properties you need without the extra lines within your code, it does not by any means chop them off the object, it is just a syntactic sugar nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ a, b } = store.getState()` is an assignment expression and the value returned by that will always be the expression on the right hand side which is `store.getState()`.

If you want only `a` and `b` then you can use and IIFE.

```js
const store = {
  getState: () => ({
    a: "test",
    b: 1,
    c: 23,
  })
}
function printState ({a, b, ...rest}) {
  console.log(a, b, rest)
}

printState((({a,b}) => ({a,b}))(store.getState()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printState({ a, b } = store.getState())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

since it's an assignment expression which returns the right hand side value, so your this function invocation is actually evaluated something like this

```
function printState(_ref) {
  var a = _ref.a,
      b = _ref.b,
      rest = _objectWithoutProperties(_ref, ["a", "b"]);

  console.log(a, b, rest);
}

printState((_store$getState = store.getState(),
             a = _store$getState.a,
             b = _store$getState.b, 
             _store$getState)
);
```

so you actually end up with `printState(store.getState())`

You can paste your code here and see [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl)